# Size UIImageView to fit exactly underneath where one line ends and right above where one line begins in a UITextView

Tags: ios, uiimage, uitextview

I would like to size a UIImageView to fit exactly underneath where one line ends and right above where one line begins in a UITextView.

**Scenario:**
I'm downloading an image from a URL using NSURLConnection. Then, I resize the image to fit the screen using the ImageIO framework. Finally, I add exclusion paths to the UITextView.textContainer so the text wraps around the image.

**Problem:**
I don't know the size of the image before hand so I have to resize it to fit. Everything works great except for the fact that the picture sometimes overlaps a line.

**Question:**
How can I make sure to size the image so that it fits exactly underneath where one line ends and right above where one line begins?

**Example:**

[image: Example of problem]

As you can see in the example above the text below the image is no longer on the lines. I was thinking I could get the remainder from the height of the UIImageView and the lineHeight but, I'm not sure what to do with it.

**Ex.** `(int)imageView.bounds.size.height % (int)self.textView.font.lineHeight`

Any guidance is greatly appreciated!

**P.S.** If my question isn't clear please let me know I will try to explain it further.

Comment: Not exactly what you asked, but how about adding the image into an `NSAttributedString`? Maybe this gives you more flexibility.

Comment: @CarstenWitzke what a great idea! NSAttributedString is definitely what I needed. Thank you for your comment. Although, I'm still having the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @CarstenWitzke I got it to work. I used an NSArributedString with an NSTextAttachment. Then, I got the remainder of the image height divided by the textView.font.lineHeight and subtracted that from the textView.font.lineHeight then added the difference to the height of the image. The only problem is sizing the image to fit the new bounds.

**Ex.**

```
UIImage * scaledImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef scale:2 orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];

NSTextAttachment * textAttachment = [[NSTextAttachment alloc] init];
textAttachment.image = scaledImage;

int remainder = (int)scaledImage.size.height % (int)floor(self.textView.font.lineHeight);
CGFloat difference = (self.textView.font.lineHeight - remainder);

textAttachment.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, scaledImage.size.width, scaledImage.size.height + difference);

NSMutableAttributedString * attributedStringWithImage = [[NSAttributedString attributedStringWithAttachment:textAttachment] mutableCopy];

NSAttributedString * newLineAttributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"\n"];

[self.textView.textStorage appendAttributedString:newLineAttributedString];
[self.textView.textStorage appendAttributedString:attributedStringWithImage];
[self.textView.textStorage appendAttributedString:newLineAttributedString];
```

**EDIT:**

Turns out I can just use the CoreGraphics framework to pad the image, which eliminates the need to resize the image to fit the new bounds.

**Ex.**

```
- (UIImage *)image:(UIImage *)image padding:(CGSize)padding
{
    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(image.size.width + padding.width, image.size.height + padding.height);

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    UIGraphicsPushContext(context);

    CGFloat x = (image.size.width + padding.width) - image.size.width;
    CGFloat y = (image.size.height + padding.height) - image.size.height;
    CGPoint origin = CGPointMake(x, y);
    [image drawAtPoint:origin];

    UIGraphicsPopContext();
    UIImage * paddedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return paddedImage;
}
```